# PHP-regexp ignore everything (even curly braces) between curly braces

Tags: php, regex

Please help, how can i retrieve text0 and text4 in the subject below:

```
text0{tex1{text2}text3}text4
```

Comment: Should it also work for `text0{text1}text2{text3}{text4}`, i.e. match three strings?

Answer (score 2):

Anchor it!

```
$text = 'text0{tex1{text2}text3}text4';
if (preg_match('/^(\w+){[\w{}]+}(\w+)$/', $text, $matches))
{
    list(,$start, $finish) = $matches;

}
```

`$start` will be "text0" and `$finish` will be "text4"

Comment: thanks so much, it works. just one more thing, why the expression given is not working for preg_replace!?

Comment: Ah you said retrieve, not replace :) When using `preg_replace` you will find the values in $1 and $2, eg. `$text = preg_replace('/^(\w+){[\w{}]+}(\w+)$/', 'Start: $1 - Finish: $2', $text);`

Comment: sorry i forgot to specify :). that exactly what i loking for, thanks...

Answer (score 0):

If you want the content outside the brackets, you can use this:

```
preg_match_all('~(?<out>[^{]++)|({(?>[^{}]++|(?2))*+})~', $string, $matches);
print_r($matches['out']);
```